# FFmpeg multi input remux multi output...no such file or directory error

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, terminal.app

I've been trying to use this to remove the audio from multiple files in the same directory and remux them back in a different location. Hoevewer I keep getting the "'/myfolder/stuff/*.mkv'" "no such file or directory" error... Anyone got an idea?
Thanks

```
for i in '/myfolder/stuff/*.mkv' ;do ffmpeg -i "$i" -map 0 -map -0:a:0 -map -0:a:1 -map 0:s:2 -c copy "/otherstuff/remux/${I%.mkv}.mkv";done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the quotes from the MKV path.  You need the shell to expand the wildcard, which it can't do if it's quoted.

Comment:  Thank you! It was basic stuff! Thanks again

Comment: You’re welcome. Please “accept” this answer if it’s working now.